# Initialise Global <Key, Value> Hash

Tags: c++, qt, initialization, global-variables

I want to intialise a QHash as a global variable.

Because it's global I can't write something like

```
QHash<QString, int> MY_HASH;
MY_HASH["one"] = 1;
MY_HASH["two"] = 2;
```

But I'm not sure how I would assign values to MY_HASH in its intialisation.

Comment: Do you have C++0x? I don't know about Qt, but in C++98/03 you cannot initialize containers with arbitrary members. In C++0x you can use the new initializer lists (but I don't know if Qt supports those).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a function?

```
typedef QHash<QString, int> hash_type

hash_type InitMyHash(){
  hash_type hash;
  hash["one"] = 1;
  hash["two"] = 2;
  // ...
  return hash;
}

hash_type MY_HASH = InitMyHash();
```

Answer (score 21):

If you use c++0x you can use an initializer_list, which would look like this:

```
QHash<QString, int> MY_HASH({{"one",1},{"two",2}});
```

In gcc, enable c++0x with the command line flag -std=c++0x

Comment: You can also use uniform initialization: `QHash<QString, int> MY_HASH{ {"one",1}, {"two", 2} };`, which would drop the extra parens.

Comment: This would only work with Qt5 where QHash has a constructor with std::initializer_list. In Qt4 there isn't a direct way to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and wrote a small template class for this. 
Somebody might find this usefull...

```
template <class T, class U>
class QHashBuilder
{
public:
    QHashBuilder & add(const T & key, const U & value)
    {
        _hash.insert(key,value);
        return *this;
    }

    QHash<T,U> build()
    {
        return _hash;
    }

private:
    QHash<T,U> _hash;
};
```

You would use it like this:

```
QHash<QString,int> hash = QHashBuilder<QString,int>().add("foo",1).add("bar",2).build();
```